# Setup database structure with books, authors, languages etc. for publishing house

Tags: customization, database, post-type, library, books

It was kind of hard to find a good title for my question. 
What I'm trying to do is setting up a homepage for a publishing company.
The website should contain all of the companies books with properties such as the author, a price, the different languages available, a description etc.

I'm new to WordPress and I've google around a lot, found some plug-ins that might be helpful but I haven't find the perfect clue so far on how to set this up correctly.

I think the books are more "objects" than just a "post entry" and they have relationships to other entities such as the language or the Author etc. So I rather want to be able to create a new book and then link it to an existing author, some languages etc.

Do you have any suggestions on how to set this up with WordPress? Usually I'd create own database tables for each entity but with WordPress, this is handled differently since everything is stored in the post-table, correct?

I'd love to get some input on that. I'm willing to code some own stuff for that but some starting hints would be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create your own custom database tables and access them with or without the WordPress wrapper.

However in this case, it sounds like you want [Custom Post Types](https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types)

I think you may have a bit of a misunderstanding as to what a "post" or "custom post type" is in WordPress. Though 100% honestly, "Custom Post Type" really is a misnomer, and a better name would be "Custom Data Type".

You can code in your own Custom Post Types or use the widely accepted and used plugins [CPT UI](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/) and [Advanced Custom Fields](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/)

You can add custom taxonomies (which is just the word we use for "Categories" when referring to Custom Post Types) as well as add custom fields which will allow you to add meta information to each one.

Essentially, either with the plugins or manually, you'll create a custom post type called "Book" and register taxonomies/terms and or use custom fields to add the relationships and entities to each one.

This is very easily doable in WordPress - let me know if you need me to expand on anything further!

Comment: Thanks @Xhynk that was really helpful! 
I came across a plugin called "toolset" have you heard of it? I'm not sure if that covers all my needs, too or I should go with you two suggestions?

Comment: You know, I haven't heard of it actually. I got my CPT feet wet with hand coding them lol.

Looking at that plugin it seems Toolset (especially Types) might actually be a great way to go. It looks like you can create great relationships very easily, and if I'm not mistaken it looks like it has a front-end template creator which would be incredibly helpful.

As a matter of fact I'm interested in it now because I do so much with custom post types, and currently running a network site that has 7 or 8 CPTs that are all very different from each other, so thanks for finding that!

Comment: I'm not sure I can advocate which would be better (ACF+CPT UI or Toolset + Types) for your particular situation - but I would absolutely look into both of them.

Based on ~10 minutes of research I'd lean slightly towards Toolset if I'm being totally honest, but I'd absolute do some more research before getting rooted into one or the other - they'll each have their pros and cons I'm sure.

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks so much! Yeah, so far I'm tempted to use toolset but I'll give the other two a try!

Comment: I've got one more question (let me know if you'd like to have a new "official" question for that)
I've got all my books in an excel sheet with the information like title, author, price, number of pages, ISBN etc. 
Now is it possible to just import these information into wordpress?

Comment: That may be a valid question on it's own, but I'll address it here: There are a few plugins, WP Ultimate CSV Importer being the one I've seen around the most. I've not used it myself, but I believe it's compatible with both CPT UI and Toolset Types. Personally, I have written a custom CSV handler that handles uploaded CSVs by breaking them into an array of `$row[$cell]` values that get added with `wp_insert_post()` and `update_post_meta()`. In lieu of writing your own handler for a single DB insert, that plugin can be found here: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-csv-importer/